# Python - regex to remove quotes from entire line in CSV file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I've seen a lot on here about how to remove quotes from within a line in a CSV file, but that's not quite the problem I have. Using something like

```
with open(path), 'wb') as myfile:
  writer = csv.writer(myfile)
```

I need to create rows consisting of the values of 3 variables. That leads to a line like this:

```
newline = var1 + " " + var2 + " " + var3
```

I want a result like `value1 value2 value3`, but instead it gives me `"value1 value2 value3"`. I tried it without the spaces in between as well and all that did was mess up the formatting without removing the quotes. I also tried adding `quoting = CSV_NOQUOTE` (or something like that) to the writer declaration, but that caused an error about missing escapechars until I added in `\n`'s, and even then it didn't get rid of the quotes. I've been scouring the pages here on SO for about an hour trying to find something but nothing I've found has worked. Could anyone please offer any advice? Thanks!

EDIT: To tie in the title, at this point I'm frustrated enough with it that I'm OK with a workaround to just get rid of the quotes with regex instead of preventing them from forming at all. I just don't know much about Python's regex, I've used it very minimally, and I'm not sure how to do basically the equivalent of a sed s/ command with it.

Comment: are you trying to create a space separated file or a comma separated file? Also the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html is pretty clear on how to change the quote characters

Comment: @Cfreak just space separated, no commas in it

Comment: The docs are also very clear on how to change the delimiter.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why this was put on hold, I displayed several things I attempted and explained what was wrong... at least I still got a working answer out of it

Comment: I voted to close it for a few reasons. 1. The question likely won't be found by someone trying to change the delimiter because you made it about regex. 2. Regexes are not a solution to this problem which indicates you don't (or didn't) really understand the problem. 3. The documentation which I already linked is very clear on how to change the delimiter. SO isn't a place to regurgitate the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show the line where you actually used `writer` to write a line to the file.  One mistake people make sometimes is to assume that `writerow` accepts something other than an iterable of values.

The following code (python 2):

```
import csv
with open("out.dat", "wb") as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    var1, var2, var3 = 3.14, 2.1728, "Fred"
    writer.writerow([var1, var2, var3])
```

produces

```
~/coding$ cat out.dat
3.14 2.1728 Fred
```

Comment: I believe that was it, thanks :) I figured it was some little mistake like that, this is just the first time I've ever worked with this stuff so I'm a little shaky still on some things

Answer (score 1):

One option for writing CSV files is to just avoid the  `csv` module entirely:

```
output = [var1, var2, var3]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as fo:
    fo.write(','.join([str(x) for x in output]) + '\n')
```

Of course you can do this with a list of lists (or any iterable) to write out multiple lines:

```
outlist = [[var1, var2, var3], [var4, var5, var6]]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as fo:
    for out in outlist:
        fo.write(','.join([str(x) for x in out]) + '\n')
```

If you wanted spaces as a separator you can use `' '.join()` instead.